# how to disable a button in its own javascript click event?

Tags: jquery, events, dynamic, bind

I have a button that is appended on a form. The form is dynamically created at some point in the application, and the button is appended like so:

```
$('#imgform').append("<center><input type='submit' value='Upload' id='#imgupload' onclick='showUploadedItem()'/>");
```

This is my code for `showUploadedItem()`:

```
function showUploadedItem () {
    $('#upload_process').show();
            // a bunch of other things to do
           $('#imgupload').prop('disabled',true);
           console.log("the submit button ID is: " + $('#imgupload').attr('id'));
}
```

But the console.log message says the button ID is `undefined`, which means that at this point in the code the button doesn't even exist. I can understand that it was dynamically created and perhaps I need to bind the event, but how did it even get clicked then, and even show the console message at all?

How can I disable this button within the function? Or is it not even possible?

Comment: maybe because you have an # in the html of the id of the button ;p

Comment: oh my... that was silly. sigh! i spent a while on this!

Comment: happens !_! , all it takes is extra couple of eyes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your html is using `id="#imgupload"` which does not appear legal.  Although for fun I was able to get a selector this to work:

```
 $('#\\#imgupload').prop('disabled',true);
```

That sure looks like a **mistake** though and your html should simply be `id="imgupload"`

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gillyspy/7vxE9/)

Also if you're using jQuery why use the inline javscript?  Simply bind an event handler (see fiddle for that too).

Answer (score 2):

It is because you habve an error in the HTML, better, in the way you note the ID. The # is used to reference an ID-Name in CSS or in jQuery (#+Name). In HTML it is only the name, like this:

```
$('#imgform').append("<center><input type='submit' value='Upload' id='imgupload' onclick='showUploadedItem()'/>");
```

Answer (score 2):

You dont need to give `#` before id. Remove that from the code

Change like this,

```
$('#imgform').append("<center><input type='submit' value='Upload' id='imgupload' onclick='showUploadedItem()'/>");
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove # from your button id will fix that.